# Why Chrome & Firefox render bootstrap CSS different than Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I am building a static web site with bootstrap. Working on local the layout looks fine, when deployed to the web, Safari OK, but Chrome and Firefox seem like if they dont support several bootstrap CSS rules or I am doing something wrong.

Safari OK
[image]

Chrome KO
[image]

Live code: (make sure to accept the certificate)
https://canales.paperplane.io/

Code (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Canales Auty</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- #Header -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/header.png"></a></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>


    <!--Navbar-->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container">
            <div class= "navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT THE FIRM</a></li>
                <li><a href="professionals.html">PROFESSIONALS</a></li>
                <li><a href="practice_areas.html">PRACTICE AREAS</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.html">NEWS ROOM</a></li>
                <li><a href="careers.html">CAREERS</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>

    <!--Mosiaco -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <img  id="d1" src="img/mosaico_1.png">
          <div class="contenthover container">
            <h3>Lut</h3>
              <p>Hola soy Lut!</p>
              <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success mybutton">Lorem ipsum</a></p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <img  id="d2" src="img/mosaico_2.png">
          <div class="contenthover container">
            <h3>Lut</h3>
              <p>Hola soy 2!</p>
              <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-success mybutton">Lorem ipsum</a></p>
          </div>
        <img src="img/mosaico_3.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"><img src="img/mosaico_4.png"><img src="img/mosaico_5.png"><img src="img/mosaico_6.png"></div>
      <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 footer">
        <p>hola</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
   <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contentHover.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('document').ready(function(){
      $('#myTootTip').tooltip();
      $('#myPopOver').popover();

      $('#d1').contenthover({
        overlay_background:'#000',
        overlay_opacity:0.8
        });

        $('#d2').contenthover({
        overlay_background:'#000',
        overlay_opacity:0.8
        });


    });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where should the two buttons sit? Your Safari screenshot doesn't show either of them.

Comment: They appear when hover over the "mosaic". Take a look at the live site https://canales.paperplane.io/ in Safari. I think the problem has to do with the jQuery plugin

Comment: You didn't actually answer my question. I did **not** ask when they appear. I asked _where_ they appear. I had already looked at your link, with Chrome. I'm not about to install anything from apple except for carbohydrates and vitamins. As always, you get better help when you make it easy for others to provide it.

Answer (score 4):

Chrome won't load non-SSL scripts over a webpage open with https://.

The best way to reference your external scripts is to not specify the protocol.

As in:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
...    
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

with **//**

Because your jQuery etc. is not loading, the site is breaking. Note: you will need to verify that your CDN will serve the files over https.

Comment: Go it, the plugin is now working after changing the script reference. Now having trouble to load the files, I could not figure out how to verify that my CDN can serve files over https. I am using github+paperplane. Also, now that I changed the script reference it does not work in local, how can I make it work?

Comment: I believe opening the file locally (without the use of a local web server) will cause the protocol to default to file://. Which won't work well. Ideally, you should setup a local web server on your development machine.